# Laravel remove item from collection

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I've got this collection:

```
return $items->map(function ($item) use ($location, $amount) {
    if($item->is_active) {
        return $this->calculate($item, array_values($location));
    }
 })
```

When the if statement is false I want to remove the item from the collection. How should I do this?

Already tried:

```
return $items->map(function ($item, $itemKey) use ($location, $amount, $items) {
    if($item->is_active) {
        return $this->calculate($item, array_values($location));
    }

    $items->forget($itemKey);
})
```

But that's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For removing items from collections depending on a condition, you can use the [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter) or [reject](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-reject) methods.

Your code should look like this:

```
return $items->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->is_active;
})->map(function ($item) use ($location, $amount, $items) {        
    return $this->calculate($item, array_values($location));
})
```